# Как выдать пользователю мут на минуту, если он спамит боту в telegram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Я сделал своего бота в telegram с довольно простыми функциями. Проблема в том, что буквально один человек может его положить простым спамом одной или несколькими командами, причем ошибку выдает именно TelegramAPI.

Вот ошибка:
`ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 429 Description: Too Many Requests: retry after 13"`

Я бы хотел, чтобы пользователь, который, допустим, отправил 10 сообщений за короткий промежуток получал мут на минуту и сообщение вроде "ха-ха попался спамер".

Бот написан на python с использованием telebot (или же pyTelegramBotAPI), а запускается все это дело на heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можешь добавить подключение к API к телеграмму в функцию, если ошибка в подключении - опять вызываешь эту функцию

```
def api():
    try:
        m = 'Здесь оставшийся бота'
    except:
        api()
api()
```

Если не хочешь сделать так, то придётся использовать базу данных - хранить переменные.
В этом поможет или `import json` или `import sqlite3`. Если не хочешь хранить переменные в базе, то храни их в самом питоне используя словарь питона (dict).
p.s В любом случае, тебе нужно `import time`. При обработке сообщения пользователя сначала проверяешь нет ли его в листе, если есть, то пиши `pass`.
`mut = {"ID_user_1": {"msg": 0, "min": 0},"ID_user_2":{"msg": 9, "min": 0}}`
Так как id - особый ключ пользователя, то повторятся он не может, для обращения к пользователю делай mut[f"{ID}"] он постарается найти его в списке.

```
try:
    mut[f"{ID}"]#Выполниться без ошибки, если пользователь есть в словаре
except:
    mut[f"{ID}"] = {"msg": 0, "min": time.time()}#При ошибке зарегистрирует пользователя
```

msg = количество сообщений обработанных от пользователя
min = когда пришло первое сообщение от этого пользователя

Думаю объяснил понятно, проверку на количество сообщений и времени сам сделаешь.

Comment: Лучше цикл засунуть и при удачном запросе выходить из него. Просто, вызывая функцию рекурсивно есть вероятность выйти за пределы рекурсии. Пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5a780831079c69cd2351a2249d6c8397c6f27a57/Check%20with%20notification/all_common.py#L82